# How to remove tint color from drawable in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-library, android-drawable

Good day. I have an issue. I change the color of EditText drawable when it's in focus and change it back to default color when focus changes. And everything was good until support library updated(that's my assumption)now the color of a drawable doesn't switch back to normal. Thank's everyone in advance =)

This is my code:

```
@Override
public Drawable setTint(Drawable d, int color) {
    Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, color);
    return wrappedDrawable;
}

@Override
public void setEditTextDrawables(final EditText editText, final int drawable) {
    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, 0, 0, 0);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(drawable);
                editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(setTint(icon,
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)), null, null, null);
            }else if (!b){
                Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(drawable);
                editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(setTint(icon,
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreyIcon)), null, null, null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this is screens from the app:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aside- you can simplify your code "if (b) else if (!b)" into just "if (b) else".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[According to the Android documentation on Drawable#setTint(int):](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setTint(int))

> To clear the tint, pass `null` to `setTintList(ColorStateList)`.

Note: Just calling `getDrawable(int)` to create a new Drawable is not sufficient to clear the tint, if you've previously set the tint on the same Drawable Id in an activity.

Answer (score 10):

Note that `setTintList( null )` will only work on API's above 21 (Android 5.0, Lollipop). Therefore the use of `ImageViewCompat` is recommended:

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList( iv,null);
```